# Capture calendar changes in Android 2.2+

Tags: android

I'm developing a calendar widget that shows calendar events. I need to capture when the user adds/modify/delete events from the calendar app, to refresh my widget. I used a broadcast receiver with this filter:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED" />

        <data android:scheme="content" />
        <data android:host="com.android.calendar" />
    </intent-filter>
```

I tested it with Android 4.2 (with a Nexus 4) and works ok. But I tested it with Android 2.3.7, and isn't working. There is any way to get it working in Android versions >= 2.2?

Thanks

Comment: what is problem in lower version

Comment: I can read events from calendar provider ("content://com.android.calendar"), but the broadcast receiver I registered to get calendar changes is not fired in Android 2.2 or 2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that I solved it using a ContentObserver inside a service. It works as I needed! :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no public API for calendar events prior to Android v14 (Ice Cream Sandwich). Prior to that, each manufacturer had to provide their own Calendar API and implementations, some of which do not provide the appropriate broadcasts upon changes.

Comment: Thanks for your response. If it's not possible, I think the best solution would be to put a "refresh button" to my widget, so the user can update it when he needs to.